# Chrome V80 features to be deprecated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Starting from Chrome V80, few events like beforeunload, unload etc are getting deprecated. How would we handle such existing events further in JavaScript?

My requirement is to alert when user tries to refresh / reload the page (F5 or ctrl+r) or browser back button, I need to alert and on confirmation, I need to reload or move back. This is in JSF2.2

But the behavior should not effect the functioning in other browsers.

Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

The `beforeunload` event will still be usable. What's being changed is the ability to perform sync XHR during page dismissal. The real harmful thing which will be deprecated in the long term is synchronous XHR, since it hurts the user experience. You'll still be able to make use of `beforeunload`. [Getting Rid of Synchronous XHRs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs) specifically mentions this:

> **Note:** We expect to remove support for synchronous use of XMLHTTPRequest() during page unloads in Chrome in version 80, scheduled to ship early in 2020.

There's also information about this specific change in [Chrome Platform Status: Disallow sync XHR in page dismissal](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912). There's more information about Chrome 80 in [Deprecations and removals in Chrome 80](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/chrome-80-deps-rems):

> Chrome now disallows synchronous calls to `XMLHTTPRequest()` during page dismissal when the page is being navigated away from or is closed by the user. This applies to `beforeunload`, `unload`, `pagehide`, and `visibilitychange`.
>
> To ensure that data is sent to the server when a page unloads, we recommend `sendBeacon()` or `Fetch` `keep-alive`. For now, enterprise users can use the `AllowSyncXHRInPageDismissal` policy flag and developers can use the origin trial flag `allow-sync-xhr-in-page-dismissal` to allow synchronous XHR requests during page unload. This is a temporary "opt-out" measure, and we expect to remove this flag in Chrome 82.

Note that popups during page dismissal will also be disallowed:

> Pages may no longer use `window.open()` to open a new page during unload. The Chrome popup blocker already prohibited this, but now it is prohibited whether or not the popup blocker is enabled.

Comment: do you know how/if we can check if a browser allow/disallow XHR in page dismissal? as sendBeacon is limited in the total payload that is sent through it - we prefer to use it only when necessary (i.e. during unload on browsers that disallow XHR in page dismissal)
we just realized that Safari IPAD also dismisses XHR and we were wondering if there's a more general way to distinguish browser support, rather than provide list of browser that we currently know that are not supporting it.

Comment: Hi, to be honest, I'm not sure. However, a good practice would be to avoid using XHR in page dismissal altogether, even if you have a legitimate use for it. As time goes on, there'll be less and less support for it, since in a lot of cases it hurts user experience.